# Groovy WsClient - Map types does not resolved properly

Tags: web-services, groovy

I'm using the following lines of code to call the web-service below:

```
 def wsdl = 'http://somewhere.com/services/msgService?wsdl'  
 proxy = new WSClient(wsdl, this.class.classLoader)  
 proxy.initialize()  

 def msg = proxy.create("com.somwhere.test.api.MsgService")
 msg.applicationName = "APP1"  
 msg.clientId = 5  
 msg.additionalProperties = [test:3]
```

for web-service

```
  <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://somewhere.com/test/api/MsgService" version="1.0" xmlns:tns="http://somewhere.com/test/api/MsgService" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
 <xs:element name="sendMessage" type="tns:sendMessage"/>  
   <xs:complexType name="sendMessage">  
    <xs:sequence>  
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="mRequest" type="tns:mServiceRequest"/>  
    </xs:sequence>  
   </xs:complexType>  
   <xs:complexType name="mServiceRequest">  
    <xs:sequence>  
     <xs:element name="additionalProperties">  
      <xs:complexType>  
       <xs:sequence>  
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="entry">  
         <xs:complexType>  
          <xs:sequence>  
           <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="key" type="xs:string"/>  
           <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="value" type="xs:anyType"/>  
          </xs:sequence>  
         </xs:complexType>  
        </xs:element>  
       </xs:sequence>  
      </xs:complexType>  
     </xs:element>  
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="applicationName" type="xs:string"/>  
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="clientId" type="xs:long"/>  
     .......  
    </xs:sequence>  
   </xs:complexType>  
  </xs:schema>
```

But get the following error:

```
Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '{test=3}' with class 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to class 'com.somwhere.test.api.MsgService$AdditionalProperties'
```

However, when the additionalProperties are an empty map, i.e. [:] it works fine.

What am I doing wrong? How must I format the map, or what other object do I need to use in order for it to work?

Comment: Can we see the code for the MsgService class?  at least the setAdditionalProperties() method and the AdditionalProperties inner class.

Comment: How do I do that? I could use msg.dump(), but that will only give me to following
sending MtServiceRequest with params: <com.somwhere.test.api.MsgService.MServiceRequest@10f965e additionalProperties=null applicationN
ame=APP1 clientId=0 >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to connect to another gateway that uses REST instead of wsdl since I didn't get it to work. I haven't tried jpertinos solution, but it looks promising.

However, I'm closing this ticket.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost a year old... I hope you already found the answer somewhere else.
Just for the record I'll add what I think

The client should have generated a class with properties named `key` and `value`, just instantiate it with the normal `create()` and set said properties.
The field `additionalProperties` might be a simple list of said 'entries' or another class wrapping the list, in which case you have to create() it also.

The best thing to do is check the list of generated classes when generating the client, creating each one and dump()ing them to see the structure.
Be prepared to write something like this.

```
new groovyx.net.ws.WSClient(
    "http://localhost/service?wsdl",
    this.class.classLoader).with {
  initialize()

  def wrapper = create('defaultnamespace.MapWrapper')
  wrapper.map = create('defaultnamespace.ArrayOfMapWrapperEntry')
  wrapper.map.mapWrapperEntry = [key1:'value1',key2:'value2'].collect{k,v->
    def entry = create('defaultnamespace.MapWrapperEntry')
    entry.key = k
    entry.value = v
    entry
  }

  send wrapper    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer jpertino! Too bad I didn't get it a year ago ;-). We have decided to connect to another gateway that uses REST instead of wsdl since I didn't get it to work. But if I am to try wsdl again in grails and have to use complex databatypes like maps I will try your solution.